# Checking that the get value is an integer (whole number)

Tags: php

I'm currently building a room booking system and was wondering how to check if the user has correctly entered an integer i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5 on the form and not anything else (i.e. left it blank, entered decimal number or alphabet).

```
$capacity = $_GET["capacity"];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[0-5]$/', $_GET['capacity']);
```

If not just limited from 0 to 5,

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_GET['capacity']);
```

Comment: Hi sorry it is the range of numbers is not limited to 5 but carries on to infinity (whole numbers).

Comment: Well, it just require a `+`, and make the range from 0 to 9

Comment: Or `preg_match('/\d+/', $_GET['capacity']);`

Answer (score 5):

As per comments check the post variable is set first, else a warning is raised in recent PHP versions:

`isset($_GET['capacity'])`

Hence, you can:

**Cast it to an int:**

`$capacity = isset($_GET['capacity']) ? (int)$_GET['capacity'] : null`

**Use a function:**

```
$capacity = is_numeric($_GET['capacity']) ? (int)$_GET['capacity'] : null;
// cast to int as is_numeric will return floats too
```

**Make it a number and compare against original input:**

`$capacity = ((int)$_GET['capacity']) == $_GET['capacity']) ? $_GET['capacity'] : null;`

This last is ideal in situations where the input might exceed MAX_INT or be altered by casting in some other way.

Comment: Make sure you check its existance first though, using `isset($_GET['capacity'])` or php will show a warning if the key does not exist.

Comment: `is_numeric` will check for more than ints though

Comment: `var_dump ( (int)"" == "");` You will get a problem if the $_GET['capacity'] is a empty string

Comment: How would you place the above in the context of an if-statement?

Comment: @CJS, I have used short-hand IF statements. Before the `?` is the condition, after the `?` is the `if-true` clause and after the `:` is the else clause. :)

Comment: Note that the else is required and there will be a fatal error if you do not provide one!

Answer (score 2):

this is a filtering job, so a good option is to use the filter module (http://php.net/filter)

so you might use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) or [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT as a flag and compare the result to false (strict comparison, to avoid confusion caused by 0)

Comment: Good answer although requires use of a potentially unavailable module.

Comment: @deed02392 right, good addition; this needs the filter module, that is enabled by default from php 5.2.0 (launched on 02 Nov 2006); before that you can just install the module if you need it

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach if you like:

```
$validValues=array('0','1','2','3','4','5');

$capacity = $_GET["capacity"];

$isValid=in_array($capacity,$validValues); //TRUE if entered value is in the valid values.
```

Values read from the $_GET are strings anyway.

[PHP manual: in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function.

Comment: This will return `true` for floats as well

Comment: @Pekka Yes, but he can later cast to integer without worries.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to match for a whole number

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]\d*$/', $variable)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if($_GET["capacity"] >= 0 && $_GET["capacity"] < 5)
{
     //prefect
}
else
{
     //invalid
}
```

Comment: Should be `&&`. Also doesn't set his variable for him.

Comment: Syntax error in the true condition clause.  I think you meant // for comment, not / for division, which is not a unary prefix operator.